# Prestashop Bug in INR Currency

Tags: php, open-source, shopping-cart, prestashop

I just came to know about one bug in Prestashop, that when I select the default website currency as INR (Indian Rupee), then the Prices are shown with comma in place of dot (.).

Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsYjm.jpg
I have shown the bug with a red arrow and circle.

And one more thing, the older price which is crossed is lower than the current price. but it says Reduced Price.

How can I remove this bug?

Comment: And the second this, that reduced price is greater than the crossed price, is obvisouly a bug

Comment: make sure you have entered `177` in Rs. and `83` in Paisa

Comment: Too many [*pricing bugs*](http://forge.prestashop.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?searcher-query=price) TMHO. I would use another product (Magento for example).

Comment: The price entered is prefilled sample data, and there are buttons to change the currency. When I click on dollar, it shows ($3.22), on pound (£2.05), on EURO (it's 2,64) and on Rupee it's (177,83). Means EURO AND RUPEE are showing price in comma in place of dot (.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bug. But it can be changed from admin part.

Comment: how to change it..
in my site also i faced to that issue
see here 
www.owntshirt.com

Answer (score 2):

It's not bug. You can configure this from admin Localization > Currencies
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this from the back-office, in tab Payment>>Currency, Select the currency you want to change an you will have the field "Format"

Edit: In new version (Ie: 1.6.0.9 which i have tested) It's in Localization > Currencies